# Groovy: Package-scoped Constructor

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to create a package-scoped constructor in Groovy beans?

If I drop `public` from the constructor, then by default, it becomes a public constructor.

I read about `@PackageScope` annotation, but it doesn't allow me to apply it on the constructor.

The reason I want package-scoped constructor in Groovy beans is to force Java code to use the corresponding bean builders to instantiate the Groovy bean classes, and not rely on the Groovy bean's constructor. The builders are separate classes that sit in the same package as the Groovy beans.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done in [`2.4.0-beta-1`](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-6839). Seems like it simply [wasn't requested before](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/PackageScope-with-constructors-td5719844.html).

How does `protected` sound?

I wrote an example with three files: a.Foo.java, b.Hidden.groovy, b.NoProblem.java:

a.Foo.java:

```
package a;

import b.Hidden;

public class Foo {
    Hidden hid = new Hidden(); // Not compiling with: 
                               // "The constructor Hidden() is not visible"
}
```

b.Hidden.groovy:

```
package b

class Hidden {
    protected Hidden() {
    }
}
```

b.NoProblem.java:

```
package b;

public class NoProblem {
    Hidden hid = new Hidden(); // Compiles fine
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! That's a bummer... I'm using Groovy-Eclipse-Compiler plugin in my Maven project, and the highest version I could go is 2.3.4 at this point.

Comment: Know that feel, bro. But, even then, 2.4 is still beta.